# How to mutate a new column with row means for select columns in grouped_tbl using dplyr r?

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate, grouped-table

I have a grouped data frame from my big dataset with ~ 800 columns and ~ 2.5 million records. I'm trying to create a row means columns for only 5-10 columns each but, not sure why, I keep getting `NA` as means for all rows.

Here's what I tried:

```
clean_bmk <- clean_bmk %>% 
                rowwise() %>%
                mutate(
                       BMK_Mean_Strategic = mean(!!strategic, na.rm = T),
                       BMK_Mean_DiffChange = mean(!!diffchange, na.rm = T),
                       BMK_Mean_Failure = mean(!!failure, na.rm = T),
                       BMK_Mean_Narrow = mean(!!narrow, na.rm = T),
                       BMK_R1_Performance = mean(!!performance_vars, na.rm=T),
                       BMK_R2_Promotion = mean(!!promote_vars, na.rm=T),
                       BMK_R3_Derail = mean(!!derail_vars, na.rm=T))


class(clean_bmk)
[1] "grouped_df" "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

When i do this, all of the columns mutated are NA. But, the following works:

```
clean_bmk$Strategic_Mean <- rowMeans(clean_bmk[,strategic], na.rm=T)
```

not sure why, and how can I make a function such that I can only send the list of vars that contains the column names, and mutates the column in the dataframe?

for example:

```
strategic <- c("column1", "column15", "column27")
```

and similar with other variables like `diffchange`, `failure`, etc.

I tried to do `dput(clean_bmk)` to share the data with you, but since the dataset is big, I couldn't get it. I'm guessing because it's a `grouped_df`, I couldn't use `[[` nor `sample()` the dataset.

Comment: If you are  doing row wise means, it would be easier with `rowMeans`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be inefficent to use `rowwise`, instead better option is `rowMeans` after `select`ing the columns of interest

```
library(dplyr)
clean_bmk %>% 
    ungroup %>%
    mutate(
      BMK_Mean_Strategic = rowMeans(select(., strategic),  na.rm = TRUE),
       BMK_Mean_DiffChange = rowMeans(select(., diffchange), na.rm = TRUE),
       BMK_Mean_Failure = rowMeans(select(., failure), na.rm = TRUE),
       BMK_Mean_Narrow = rowMeans(select(., narrow), na.rm = TRUE),
       BMK_R1_Performance = rowMeans(select(., performance_vars), na.rm=TRUE),
       BMK_R2_Promotion = rowMeans(select(., promote_vars), na.rm=TRUE),
       BMK_R3_Derail = rowMeans(select(., derail_vars), na.rm=TRUE))
```

---

Using a reproducible example

```
data(mtcars)
#v1 <- c('mpg', 'disp')
mtcars %>%
   transmute(newMean = rowMeans(select(., v1), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
   head  
#                  newMean
#Mazda RX4           90.50
#Mazda RX4 Wag       90.50
#Datsun 710          65.40
#Hornet 4 Drive     139.70
#Hornet Sportabout  189.35
#Valiant            121.55
```

Comment: I tried that. I get this error: `Error in rowMeans(select(., strategic), na.rm = T) : 'x' must be numeric`

Comment: @user1828605 Can you please  check  if the columns are numeric.  I  am assuming that the columns are numeric.  E.g. this works with a reproducible example `v1 <- c('mpg', 'disp'); mtcars %>% transmute(newMean = rowMeans(select(., v1), na.rm = TRUE)) %>% head  %>% pull(newMean)#[1]  90.50  90.50  65.40 139.70 189.35 121.55`

Comment: They are. This is what's confusing me a lot, and that's why I also included the `class` of the `df` in my question. I'm not sure, but I have a feeling that it also adds the grouped ID which is not numeric. So, whenever I try to run the rowMeans like you showed above, is it also taking the id? and trying to take mean? if that's the case, I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @user1828605 iff you  already  have a  grouped_df attribute, then do `clean_bmk %>% ungroup %>%..` and apply the rowMeans because for rowMeans, you don't need any group attribute

Comment: @akun. That's it!!!! That was the cause and ungroup() worked! That's awesome how quick you came up with that!! Thanks a bunch!